# APK is reading incompatible on my real device

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, apk

My Android Studio will build my Flutter app fine. Everything seems to be in order, and I can run it virtually on my Pixel XL API 30 Device. I exported the unsigned apk file, and uploaded to my GDrive to use on my physical Galaxy S10+ Phone, running Android 12. I download the APK file, and it says "App not installed as app isn't compatible with your phone"

I can't really tell if this is an export setting issue or a phone issue. My phone has 3rd party apps on it, so I feel like its an Android Studio config issue on export?

I've exported APKs from Unity dozens of times, but honestly less familiar with what I have to include for on Android Studio for exports. I assumed it would just use what is running on my virtual device.

Comment: `unsigned apk file` all installable APKs need to be signed, either with your 'debug key' or your 'release key'.

Comment: Ah that explains it. I was unsure if test ones could be unsigned if they weren't going up on the store. Let me update this thread after I try that later. That would be fantastic if that fixes it.